# An application locks up the previously-used application, and nothing else. Why might this happen?

Tags: windows, debugging

I am not a software developer. I program PLCs, and one particular PLC programming software has had a bug for years. I'm hoping to give the dev some info so that they can fix the product I use. Windows 10 by the way. Problem goes like this:

I connect to a PLC using "Product X". During the network connection and program verification, which can take minutes, Prod X will lock up whatever open program I used just before. The affected program doesn't seem to go into a "Not Responding" state. But the GUI won't allow input and it can't be brought again into focus from the taskbar. If clicked, the affected app's window won't come into the foreground. It could be Calculator, Microsoft Edge, Chrome, OneNote, Excel. It doesn't matter. I can use an app if it wasn't in focus just prior to the PLC connection process.

What might be a reason for this? I figure it has to be network related, and possibly there is a shared library not getting relinquished that is relevant to the Windows environment, specifically the program in focus. I'd love for this to be resolved, but I've reached the end of my usefulness here.

There is nothing else I can do. I'm hoping users have some familiarity with this type of issue.

I don't have any code to post.

Comment: I suspect they are doing something funny with `GetForegroundWindow()`.

Comment: Thank you! I will bring that to the team.